# Random indexing in Pandas Series created from python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

For the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dictionary = {'D' : 10, 'B' : 20, 'C' : 30} 

series = pd.Series(dictionary) 
print(series)
```

I am getting output :

```
D     10
B     20
C     30
dtype: int64
```

but the expected output should be :

```
B    20
C    30
D    10
dtype: int64
```

Why is this happening?
Help me with this.

Comment: Why are you expecting the index to be sorted? You can do `series.sort_index()` if it needs to be sorted.

Comment: @TobyPetty I read it from somewhere that "By default, a Series will be created from dictionary where the index is drawn from the sorted keys." Also, see code 2 of this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-pandas-series-from-dictionary/

Comment: See the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html - it states `Changed in version 0.23.0: If data is a dict, argument order is maintained for Python 3.6 and later.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the pandas documentation of [pd.series()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series):

> Changed in version 0.23.0: If data is a dict, argument order is maintained for Python 3.6 and later.

So the output you get is the expected behavior for the current versions of Python and pandas.